# Adminstrator command runs fine using terminal but not in a .bat file

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch-file, windows-11

I have the following command:

`& '.\FocusAssist\LGPO\LGPO.exe' /t '.\FocusAssist\disable_toast_notifications.txt'`

If I open up Windows Powershell using Administrator privileges the command runs successfully.

However, if I put this command into a .bat file (let's call it `disable_toast_notifications.bat`) the command fails to run. I have tried:

- Running the .bat file normally and using the "Run as administrator" option
- Having either `'.\FocusAssist\LGPO\LGPO.exe' /t '.\FocusAssist\disable_toast_notifications.txt'` or `& '.\FocusAssist\LGPO\LGPO.exe' /t '.\FocusAssist\disable_toast_notifications.txt'` as the contents of `disable_toast_notifications.bat` (the difference is the `&` in the beginning of the command).

How can I successfully run this .bat file? Do .bat files require a different syntax?

Comment: Are you sure the .bat file is running in powershell and not a command prompt?

Comment: I am simply double-pressing the file on Windows Explorer. I assume that this runs the file as a command prompt? If so, how to run it in Powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run a batch file as administrator by default it runs in:
C:\windows\system32

Thus probably not finding that relative path you specified:
'.\FocusAssist\LGPO\LGPO.exe

If after running the batch as admin you want to go back to it's original path you can put something like:

cd /d "%~dp0"

Somewhere in the beginning of the batch file.

Also you should use double quotes not single